# What is the difference between these two syntaxes

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

i have these two syntaxes these syntaxes are almost doing same thing but i am getting confused what is the differnce between these two,and which one is more suitable

```
<button onClick={() => dispatch(addTodo(todo))}>ADD</button>
 <button onClick={dispatch(addTodo(todo))}>ADD</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button onClick={() => dispatch(addTodo(todo))}>ADD</button>` will get dispatch the action when you click on `Add` button.

`<button onClick={dispatch(addTodo(todo))}>ADD</button>` will dispatch action when your component gets mounted

And you should avoid using `<button onClick={dispatch(addTodo(todo))}>ADD</button>`